# Run the YAML pipeline from another Azure DevOps Git repository

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

Could you please help me. How I can run the YAML pipeline from another Azure DevOps Git repository? I have two repositories, one for templates, one for code source. My code:

```
resources:      
  repositories: 
  - repository: CodeServerGit
    name: BoxServer/CodeServerGit
    type: git 
    #connection: CodeServerGit
    ref: /v1/dev
   # source: /v1/dev
```

I have an error

> [error]Project file(s) matching the specified pattern were not found.

I see that I am in the wrong repository. Assembly goes in the repository in which the template is located, and does not connect to the repository in which the code.

Comment: Hi, Vitalii, any process on this issue? could you achieve it successfully now? If yes, you can [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) that will help other community members who easier search this useful information, it just a reminder :)

Answer (score 3):

Since what you want to link is Azure Devops git repos, please check below sample which work for me:

```
resources:      
  repositories: 
  - repository: {repos name}
    name: {project name}/{repos name}
    type: git 
    ref: master #branch name

jobs: 
    - template: azure-pipelines-1.yml@{repos name}
```

---

The above script is not very complicated, but there are many places should be **noted**.

**(1)** The project which store the template YAML file should be in the same organization.

**(2)** For the value of `ref`, if what you want is **branch**, just input the branch name here. The server will automatically add `refs/heads` before the value after the queue start.

If here you want to specify a **tag**, you must fill it with a completed format: `refs/tags/{tag name}`.

**(3)** Do not forget to specify the **repos name** after `@` when you trying to call one template

See the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#using-other-repositories).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you please tell me how I can specify another branch in my template? Thanks.

Comment: @VitaliiFedorenko Does another branch means like feature branch?

Comment: for example, if I wanted to take the code from another repository and run it using this template

Comment: @VitaliiFedorenko Just specify the branch name as the `ref` value which this template file exists.

Comment: I'm sorry, I probably explained it wrong. Can I indicate in the template in which I described the steps of the build, indicate another branch? Thanks

Comment: @VitaliiFedorenko If I am not misunderstand, do you mean specify another branch in this build which is using template resource? Feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes, something like, for example,

`
resources:      
 
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: beta
      project: BoxServer
      source: v1/dev
      branch: v1/dev

steps:

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Build'
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: 'src/Emw.*/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration)'
`

Comment: ```
resources:      
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: beta
      project: BoxServer
      source: v1/dev
      branch: v1/dev
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Build'
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: 'src/Emw.*/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration)'
```

Comment: @VitaliiFedorenko, Okay.Seems got what you want to achieve. Use `source` and `ref` together in this template build? If this, afraid to say, you can write them both. **BUT**, actually, the server can only compile the value of `ref`. The value of `source`, it has no any affect to this build.